# How to populate a fragment and firebase with information from a form without authentication

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, data-retrieval

I am pretty new on Android studio and Firebase and what I am trying to do is populate a fragment on my app and firebase at the same time when I click on  a button after filling a form. I am not talking about athentication. My app is crashing.

Here is the fragment where the form is

```
public class Entreprisesfrag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference dbref;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    public Entreprisesfrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entreprises, container, false);

        recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recv);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbref= firebaseDatabase.getReference("Entreprises");


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>
                (entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_cardview, ViewHolder.class,dbref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, entreprises_class model, int position) {


            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.recherche_activity_menu_item, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do search code here
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.recherche)
        {

        }
        else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.filtrer)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erreur de connexion ! Vérifiez l'adresse email utilisée et le mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Getter and Setter Class

```
public class entreprises_class {

    String nom, secteur, ville, image;

    public entreprises_class(){}

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getSecteur() {
        return secteur;
    }

    public void setSecteur(String secteur) {
        this.secteur = secteur;
    }

    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }

    public void setVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }



}
```

Firebase Class

```
public class Firebase_class {
    DatabaseReference dbref;
    Boolean aBoolean=null;
    ArrayList<entreprises_class> entreprises= new ArrayList<>();

    public Firebase_class(DatabaseReference dbref) {
        this.dbref=dbref;
    }

    public Boolean save(entreprises_class ent_class)
    {
        if(ent_class==null){
            aBoolean=false;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                dbref.child("Entreprises").push().setValue(ent_class);
                aBoolean=true;

            }
            catch (DatabaseException databaseException)
            {
                databaseException.printStackTrace();
                aBoolean=false;
            }
        }
        return aBoolean;
    }

    public void fetchdata(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        entreprises.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            entreprises_class ent_class= ds.getValue(entreprises_class.class);
            entreprises.add(ent_class);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<entreprises_class> retrieve()
    {
        dbref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
            @Nullable String s) {
                fetchdata(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
            @Nullable String s) {
                fetchdata(dataSnapshot);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
            @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return entreprises;
    }
}
```

ViewHolder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView, textView1, textView2;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_nom);
        textView1= itemView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_secteur);
        textView2= itemView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_sous_secteur);
        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise_image);

    }

}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{
    Context cntx;
    ArrayList<entreprises_class> entreprises;

    public Adapter(Context cntx, ArrayList<entreprises_class> entreprises) {
        this.cntx = cntx;
        this.entreprises = entreprises;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate 
    (R.layout.entreprises_cardview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(entreprises.get(position).getNom());
        holder.textView1.setText(entreprises.get(position).getSecteur());
        holder.textView2.setText(entreprises.get(position).getVille());
        Picasso.get().load(entreprises.get(position) 
        .getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entreprises.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have stack trace. This can help us  know what is the problem.

Comment: Is crashing with what error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference